# PHP with NGINX can't connect to MySQL on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, nginx

I'm having some difficulty setting up Nginx with PHP and MYSQL on mac, where I cannot make any connection to the database.  If I spawn a server using php -S, I can connect without problem.   However Nginx running on port 8080 is unable to connect at all.

I've installed (and now uninstalled) php with brew, which might be an issue because it looks like PHP comes installed on mac.  Running php -v shows me running on 7.1.16, but the brew installed version was 7.2+.  I have PHP-FPM running on localhost:9000.

I've checked my php.ini files, but I only see extensions for mysqli and pdo_mysql, which I've tried to enable but still no luck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the error message you get when trying to connect?

Comment: I've been checking through the logs, but have been unable to find anything useful.  Do you know of any other location where PHP might store logs other than /var/log?

Comment: no, I mean, this would be in your nginx logs presumably. `/var/log/nginx/error.log` probably?

Comment: Doesn't look like any errors are being logged through Nginx.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding - Can you connect to a php page on your nginx server? If so, can you try to connect to mysql with php there? You must get an error message there, not in the logs (assuming you have error reporting all the way on).

Comment: I can connect to php with nginx, but php cannot connect to mysql.  I do have error logging in my php.ini file.  I've also tried to set the error log location, but it still doesn't seem to generate the log.

Comment: Right, but when you do `$mysqli = @new mysqli('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db'); die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);` or however you're connecting with php, it must show an error right on your web page. Forget the logs for a moment.

Comment: Did you try to use Docker ? It can be usefull on mac to avoid having a lot of software installed on it

Comment: I do have my app setup with Docker, however preferred to run directly.  Outputting the error gives: _No such file or directory_

Comment: I have to agree with @Hooli - preference or not, you're going to have a hell of a lot easier time with Docker. Your error is not a mysql error at all, so I don't even know what to begin to tell you unfortunately.

Comment: You know that when you run php from the command line that is not php-fpm, right? They are totally identical for the first 3 letters of the programme name, but no further than that.